Looking for a self-hosted notes app with server app or synchronization via ssh
My setup is the following: a home server on linux, a mobile computer on Windows and my iPhone.
I am looking for a self hosted notes app, that:

I can run on my linux server
is able to synchronise to Windows and iPhone via ssh, so I do not need to setup a webserver with ssl
has a native iPhone app
has a native windows app
supports pasting images on the app

Does anybody have an idea if something like this exists? I was trying Joplin, but I would have to open the joplin server to the internet, which seems to me much harder to get secure than a plain ssh server.
Kind regards Bastian
